# Error in Netbeans, <TestGeometricObject> is not abstract

Tags: java, abstract

This is my assignment:  Design an interface named Colorable with a void method name howToColor(). Every class of a colorable object must implement the Colorable interface. Design a class named Square that extends GeometricObject and implements Colorable.  Implement howToColor to display a message “Color all four sides”. 
Write a test program that creates an array of five GeometricObjects. For each object in the array its howToColor method if it is colorable.

I'm getting an error in Netbeans on this line: 
    GeometricObject[] objects = {new Square(), new Triangle(), new...
saying  is not abstract and does not override abstract method howToColor() in Colorable.  Thanks in advance!!!

```
public abstract class TestGeometricObject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GeometricObject[] objects = {new Square(), new Triangle(), new Circle(), new Trapezoid() {}, new Octagon()};
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        GeometricObject object = objects[i];
        if (objects instanceof Colorable[]) {
            Colorable colorable = (Colorable) object;
            colorable.howToColor();
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Not colorable");
    }

    }
}
}

public interface Colorable {
    public String howToColor();

}

public abstract class GeometricObject implements Colorable {

  /**Default construct*/
  public GeometricObject() {
  }

}

public abstract class Square extends GeometricObject implements Colorable {

public Square() {

}

public void Trapezoid() {

}

@Override
public String howToColor(){
    return "Color all four sides";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the meaning of abstract confused. Abstract means that it says a method should be there without defining it. For each class where you get the error:

> SomeClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method howToColor() in Colorable.

add to that class the definition of `howToColor(`:

```
public string howToColor(){
    return "color it somehow";
}
```

changing the returned string to correspond with the shape. Don't make that class abstract.

Comment: Oops! I answered Jin Kwon instead of you. Thanks. I'm not getting any compiler errors, but there is no output. It's supposed to return how to color the shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just print your error message again.

```
TestGeometricObject.java:4: error: Square is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

See?

```java
public abstract class Square
```

Why don't you remove the `abstract` modifier from `Square` class?

---

**UPDATE per OP's comments**

I can't help but assuming without the full source code. And here comes what I did for you.

Following source code

```
public class TestGeometricObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GeometricObject[] objects = {new Square(), new Triangle()};
        for (GeometricObject object : objects) {
            System.out.println(object.howToColor());
        }
    }
}

interface Colorable {
    String howToColor();
}

abstract class GeometricObject implements Colorable {
}

class Square extends GeometricObject {
    @Override
    public String howToColor(){
        return "Color all four sides";
    }

}

class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    @Override
    public String howToColor(){
        return "Color all three sides";
    }

}
```

Prints

```
$ java TestGeometricObject
Color all four sides
Color all three sides
```

Comment: I did that, but there is still the same error on this line:          GeometricObject[] objects = {new Square(), new Triangle(), new Circle(), new Trapezoid() {}, new Octagon()};

Comment: Oh, wait. I need to change something.

Comment: I believe you gonna remove `abstract` modifier not just from `Square` but also all other classes (`Triangle`, `Circle`, and so on).

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not getting any compiler errors, but there is no output. It's supposed to return how to color the shapes.